# No options while editing a post body

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editor

I was browsing the review queues and tried editing a question. There were no options under the body. I was pretty confused so I skipped the question only to see it was happening on other questions too.

After hitting space in the body a few times I clicked 'save edits'. The error 'Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?' showed and all icons and options returned.

Has this happened to anyone else?

[image: See below:]

Comment: I'm getting something very similar, but I have edit privileges, so the behavior is slightly different. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384455/6083675

Comment: @Laurel Yeah, very similar, the only way I was able to continue editing was by clicking  'Save Edits' (even if I had not done anything) and everything would return to normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that. We rolled out a substantial refactoring of our JS (including converting some of it to Typescript), and evidently a few things got missed. We've rolled back the change in order to investigate and re-test.