# Un-upvote an old post is not showing any warning message

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting, warning

**Except Meta Stack Exchange**, if I'm trying to un-upvote an old post which was not edited in the recent time, previously I used to receive the following warning message in all the Stack Exchange sites.

Screenshot taken from *Meta Stack Exchange*:

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange]

In plain text:

> You last voted on this question {date} at {time}. Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited.

The warning message is not displaying in all the other Stack Exchange sites. When I'm un-upvote it looks like the vote count was reversed and no warning message, but after refresh the page, the old vote count is retained.

---

**Configuration**

I can repro this issue from `Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131` and `Mozilla Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit)` in `WIndows 10 Pro` without any userscript installed.

Receiving the following console error:

In Google Chrome:

> Uncaught Svg icon getters must be initialized before an icon can be retrieved

In Mozilla Firefox:

> uncaught exception: Svg icon getters must be initialized before an icon can be retrieved

Comment: Your scenario isn't entirely clear. At what point do you upvote the question? After you've upvoted it, why wouldn't the question then appear as edited and allow you to un-upvote it? (At some point, edits with the 5-minute grace period will become *actual* and give an edited status.) Also, are you saying that you click on the voting button but the vote change is ignored *and* you are not presented with any message?

Comment: I repro this on Stack Overflow. I can remove my vote from an old post, where I last voted a *very* long time ago.  There is no warning message displayed, and the vote appears to be successfully removed.

Comment: @CodyGray After your refresh the page, the previous voting count will retain. Seems it looks like the voting is reversed but not.

Comment: Ah, then this is almost certainly related to [the re-emergence of JavaScript breakage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384481/possible-bug-in-stack-overflow-editor-not-showing-any-functional-options-to-for) (also [reported here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327586/no-options-while-editing-a-post-body) earlier).

Comment: @JasonBassford Please try to un-upvote any post from your [voting list](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/291924/jason-bassford?tab=votes&sort=upvote), usally when un-upvote the old post it throwing the warning message.

Comment: @CodyGray So, you're saying that you can change your vote on a question that has *not* been edited?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @Jason.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, thank you. That makes this description much clearer. (The mention of the five-minute voting period and lack of message—but without explaining the actual result—hadn't made the problem at all clear.)

Comment: @Arulkumar I would recommend editing your question to make it clear that the bug is that you can change votes on posts that have not been edited. (The five-minute grace period seems to have no bearing on this, and you hadn't made it clear that your vote actually *was* changed.)

Comment: Unclear what you ask. You say "not showing any message" but then you post a message. No idea what you mean, whatever the bug is, it is not reported correctly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have mentioned as _Except Meta Stack Exchange_ the issue occurs. Screenshot taken from Meta Stack Exchange and the same message is not displaying from other Stack Exchange sites. Please read the question again.

Comment: I see now. No repro for me (Chrome 74, no userscripts), so it's either browser specific, or something on your end, e.g. userscript messing with the JS. (since others can repro, likely some popular script e.g. SOUP)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can repro from `Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131` and `Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit)` in WIndows 10 Pro without user script installed

Comment: Any client side errors in dev console? (When you try to undo the vote)

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is a console error, updated in the post.

Comment: Heh. So [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315456/no-error-handling-for-posting-as-a-guest), in a different form.